Часть слайдера сделать прозрачнее(HTML, CSS, JS)
я немного новичок в сфере frontend-development. Верстаю сайт по макету из фигмы. Как можно сделать часть слайдера чуть прозрачной, как на макете?

Как написать стили для слайдера в таком случае

Используйте opacity: 0.5; на объекты, которые нужно сделать прозрачными. варьируется от 0 до 1 прозрачность. Если нужно только задний фон сделать прозрачным, но не контент, тогда самому блоку, которому вы задали background, нужно переписать в формате rgba(32, 242, 255, 0.5) где 0,5 это и будет прозрачность.

Используйте opacity:
element {
    opacity: 0.5;
}

Нужно заменить element на CSS-селектор элемента, которого надо сделать прозрачнее (можно использовать дополнительный класс, например, .translucent).
Если надо оставить контент элемента непрозрачным, а фон полупрозрачным, используйте цвет фона с альфа-каналом (MDN документация для RGBA и HEX):
element {
    /* rgba альфа канал */
    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
    /* hex альфа канал */
    background-color: #ff000088;
}

В этом примере использован красный цвет.
Можно использовать и тот и другой формат, но rgba более читабелен и прост.
Опять же, можно изменять альфа-канал (0.5 для RGBA и 88 для HEX, в конце).
